# programming an android app - where to start

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I have been looking all over the internet and i found some good guides for programing in android but i still dont fully understand what exactly is going on with this thing

i thought this would be like programing a java program but its very different.. there are lots of xml files and there is this thing called "activity" and an "intent" of which i dont understand how they work.. same with the way of displaying things..there is this xml file that designs the way the app looks but when you i used this code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(FirsttimeActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    setContentView(textView);
}
```

the text box that was there before disappeared and a normal text appeared instead.. what just happand here? how do i replace the text with something else after that? how do i go back to the normal view?

so my qoustions are as follows:

what does an "activity" mean? whats the parallel in a normal java project?
whats an intent and how does it work?
how do i control the display? how come it changed when i entered that code?

thanx

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/index.html

Comment: Pretty much all of these questions are answered by [the Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html), particularly the [Application Fundamentals section.](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html)

Comment: About `activity` and your cicle: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html and about `Intent`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: Since it's fairly obvious that this is your first experience with Android development, you should have definitely gone to the official developer's site and read as much of the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/index.html) as you could have before asking such a question here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An Activity is an essential part of Android development. Its basically a class which you can use to represent any number of UIs. The onCreate method is not a constructor, but is called as soon as the Activity is started, so initializing your information in there is a good idea. The program knows which Activity it is starting with within your android manifest file with the line of code

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

There is no real parallel to a 'normal' java project. An intent is used to pass information from Activity to Activity. The best way to learn about Intents is to read about them here : 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

The actual visual part of what you see, is controlled in the XML files which are located in the /res/layout/ folder within your project.

Comment: the stuff i put in the xml file in /res/layout/ are only displayed on the first screen?

Comment: well, the file that is defaulted there is called main.xml......For that to displayed, you will need to call    setContentView(R.layout.main), if you create a new XML file called foo.xml, whenever you call setContentView( R.layout.foo ), the view will change to what you have in that XML file

Answer (score 1):

This is all very basic information that you should know before coming here. A more detailed guide and tutorial can be found the Android developer's [site](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html). Go through the tutorials and guides and learn as much as you can before looking anywhere else or asking on Stack Exchange. I've provided some basic answers here, but you can find better details on the site I linked earlier.

In basest terms, an `Activity` is a specific screen and is the building block of the typical Android application. Each screen that you see in an Android application such as the settings screen or main application screen is a single `Activity`.

XML files are used to design the layouts of each `Activity` that requires a graphical interface. When you used

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setTextSize(40);
textView.setText(message);
```

You created an entirely new `TextView` widget. To link to a widget that has been described in the XML file, you call the `findViewById(int id)` method.

An `Intent` is how an Android application passes information between Activities and launches new Activities.

Answer (score 0):

If you visit http://developer.android.com you can find all the info you need.
Learn programming Android requires some studying. The official developer site is the best point to start.